# How to bind SQLite FTS4 query params in Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, data-binding, full-text-search

I wonder how to bind `SQLite FTS` query params for sanitizing inputs. I was trying to run a raw query like below which ended up with a runtime error.

When I created table. It worked fine with,

```
private const val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE entry USING FTS4 (title, subtitle);"
db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
```

Some entries are inserted into DB successfully with,

```
val values = ContentValues().apply {
    put("title", "Test title")
    put("subtitle", "Test subtitle")
}
val newRowId = db?.insert("entry", null, values)
```

Now I am running raw query like,

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM entry WHERE title MATCH '?'"
val args = arrayOf("Test")
val cursor: Cursor? = db.rawQuery(query, args)
```

**This fails with runtime error**,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.achellies.kotlin/com.achellies.kotlin.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:240)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:194)
```

In case of `non FTS` database we can query with `=?` binding. So, how can I sanitize for `FTS4 SQLite` query which has a `MATCH` clause?

Comment: Did you try `= ?` ?

Comment: @forpas did you mean ‘MATCH = ?’ ?  No I didn’t try that

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Try: `SELECT * FROM entry WHERE title MATCH ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM entry WHERE title MATCH '?'"
```

`'?'` should be written without single quote. Proper way is,

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM entry WHERE title MATCH ?"
```